# How to execute the c executable file which takes input from file using java?

Tags: java, c, executable

This is what I am doing:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

Process proc = rt.exec("./Hello" + " < in.txt");
```

It takes input from file and prints it on `stdout`. But this is not getting executed. How do I make it happen?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing each argument separately instead of combining whole command in a String:

```
String[] cmd = {"./Hello","<","in.txt"};

 Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
 Process proc = rt.exec(cmd);
```

Hope this helps;

Answer (score 0):

My take on this is, that you want to get the output from the executed command. When calling `Runtime.exec("<some command>")` Java sets up its separate IO-Streams to read and write to the executed command.

If you want to print the result of the command to the command-line, then you could do something like this:

```
public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        int read;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("echo HELLO-THERE");
        InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
        while (is.available() > 0) {
            read = is.read(buffer);
            System.out.println(new String(buffer, 0, read, "UTF-8"));
        }
    }
}
```

which yields this:

```
HELLO-THERE
```

Generally, in situations like this, you are best off reading the java doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/